# How to get the address from the block to which BEP20 tokens came?

Tags: node.js, web3js

```
var Block = await web3.eth.getBlock(block_identifier = web3.eth.defaultBlock, full_transactions = true);
var transactions = Block.transactions;
```

This is how I get transactions on the BSC network, but how do I get transactions in a block with BEP-20 tokens? Like Paraswap?

I tried, but I don't understand how it can be traced

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get USDC (or any non-ETH value) from transaction using web3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177717/get-usdc-or-any-non-eth-value-from-transaction-using-web3-js)

Comment: @PetrHejda, no.